# Paypal API Error 10002 although credentials are right

Tags: api, paypal

I know this question has been asked a thousand times before and I came across some topics here when doing some Google research about this.

My problem is: I get an Error 10002 - "Security header invalid". I checked the credentials and they are right. I use the live credentials for the live mode and am connecting to the right server and endpoint.

I am using a Paypal class written in PHP. When using it in Sandbox mode it works fine. If I am using it in live mode it shows the checkout as we know it: on the left the item and the total sum and on the right the login screen.
Now I log in with my Paypal account credentials and the API asks me to confirm the purchase. I do so. When it is at the point where it would execute the transaction and redirects to the "Purchase successful" page it suddenly says the above mentioned error.

So I did some testing on my machine with the sandbox account. Assuming that I would use invalid API credentials I would not ever see the checkout (on the left summary on the right login form). But I do. First if I confirm the transaction the API is not okay with the credentials anymore.

How can the credentials first be valid and later on they are invalid? This doesn't make any sense to me. When testing in Sandbox mode everything works fine.

I am using this library:

http://www.php-suit.com/paypal

Help would be highly appreciated as I can't find any explaination for that behaviour anymore. Again: I checked the credentials and they are right.

Best regards,
extrawagant

Comment: What payment method are you using? You shouldn't be getting an API error like 10002 on the PayPal site at all. Those kind of errors are specifically returned in the response - before you would redirect your  buyer to PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to double check again the API [credentials](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/) or the endpoint used.

The error "Error 10002 - Security header invalid" is returned for these common reasons:

- Providing the username/password to your actual PayPal account, instead of your API username and API password. We generate your API username and password when you generate your API certificate/signature.
- Using the same API information for Sandbox and Live. You need to generate separate API information for your Sandbox and Live accounts.
- You have not updated the [endpoint](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/endpoints/) to point to PayPal's live API servers.
- Trailing or leading white space on any of the characters.

E.g. if you are using the Live Environment endpoint, make sure you are using the credentials created in the Live account. Double check for white spaces when you are pasting into your integration. If you are using the variable "SUBJECT" double check the value inserted.